# DAX Get child columns associated with a max value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a simple parent child one to many table relationship. I want to get columns associated with the most recent child.

Example:

Parent:

ID, Name

Child:

ID, ParentID, Date, Amount

I want to add a column to the Parent that shows the Most recent child's amount. I have a relationship set up between these tables.

Comment: Your example is a bit scarce. Try adding a few more rows' worth of data together with your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

```
New Column =
var _max = maxx(filter(child, child[parent] = parent[ID]), Child[Date] )
return maxx(filter(child, child[parent] = parent[ID] && Child[Date] = _max ), child[Amount])
```

This worked!